# Is this sha256sum from an official ubuntu iso?

Tags: 20.04, iso

I downloaded an image days ago without verifying its hash (I forgot, I always did)

```
ubuntu-20.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
```

the hash is

```
e2ce1771e352b04cfdef5bf6583f6a7d62b1f2967903fae512506d18d251a434
```

How do I know it's a genuine hash? At least one from the ubuntu team?

By searching this hash on google I found some people which have it too, but I couldn't find it on ubuntu's website.

I see that now there is a `ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso`. What is the difference?

Comment: 20.04.2.0 ISO has fix as per https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-February/000265.html  For the sha256, download it yourself and check https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.2.0/

Comment: @guiverc oh ok. How can I see the sha256sum of the previous image?

Comment: On the download page click link that says "verify your download" it will display small popup with the hash and instructions on how to verify the iso.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz yes but this is the for new ISO, not the one I downloaded days ago

Comment: Personally I'd `zsync` the older ISO to update it (ie. download the differences only) so it's the 20.04.2.0 ISO  (unless bandwidth quotas don't impact you, in which case you can download the fixed ISO..)

Comment: @guiverc thanks, I already have the newest one, but I was wondering if I downloaded an infected image for some reason. So I just wanted to see if the offical `ubuntu-20.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` (without the .0) has this hash. On http://releases.ubuntu.com/ there are thee 24.04 but all of them have the same .iso hash which is not right I guess

Comment: Your hash is correct:  https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04/SHA256SUMS

Comment: @Terrance THANKS!!! I guess I did verify before using but I forgot.

Answer (score 3):

20.04.2.0 ISO has fix as per https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-February/000265.html

> Shortly after the release of Ubuntu 20.04.2, on Thursday February 4
> 2021, a regression was discovered[1] which means that on certain
> systems and under certain specific conditions the Ubuntu installer can
> fail to install a Linux kernel. This renders the system unable to
> boot.

For the sha256, download it yourself and check https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.2.0/

Personally I'd `zsync` the older ISO to update it (ie. `zsync` will download only the differences) so your 20.04.2 ISO will be updated to 20.04.2.0 ISO (*unless bandwidth quotas don't impact you, in which case you can download the fixed ISO*)

Comment: I want to verify if the hash I have (`e2ce1771e352b04cfdef5bf6583f6a7d62b1f2967903fae512506d18d251a434`) is an official one. I already have the new 20.04.0 and already verifies its new hash

Comment: Canonical folks have taken to keeping fewer *older* ISOs around, esp. if flaws are detected... If I was looking for what you want, I'd look in the iso.QA site.. esp. as I was asked to run some QA-tests on 20.04.2.0 earlier today, and as of an hour ago; the infrastructure still had 20.04.2.0 present (no 20.04.3 *daily* had replaced it as of an ~hour ago.. and a number of prior ISOs & details can usually be found; ie. you're after the prior RC which was 20.04.2....  It's where I'd look for it...

Comment: unfortunately it's not there: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/focal/daily-live/20210204/focal-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: :(   I noted some build issues on IRC (*builds failed*), which caused a new build to be *kicked off* which probably caused prior to be dropped off (not replaced by anything as next build didn't complete)... Sorry, I'm involved with a *flavor* so didn't take that much notice (*didn't impact us so I ignored it*)

Answer (score 1):

The hash for file `ubuntu-20.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` is found in https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04/SHA256SUMS and it matches the hash.

Contents:

```
bc05bf3296220c4c85415c76aceac834cba70cb3bc447240c7de1655bf4d7c1e *ubuntu-20.04-beta-desktop-amd64.iso
20d1e68414efab4a832c58298677a491a57e3e661f64081f081912d54d29fc6a *ubuntu-20.04-beta-live-server-amd64.iso
e5b72e9cfe20988991c9cd87bde43c0b691e3b67b01f76d23f8150615883ce11 *ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso
caf3fd69c77c439f162e2ba6040e9c320c4ff0d69aad1340a514319a9264df9f *ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso
46d5ee0843e5da7e170fa84b5f4e9e474456180659221ec6cc2dc60f6fcd1b06 *ubuntu-20.04-live-server-arm64.iso
bca032e9256556bbe8e2aef4aa5f433ef667f78135f538f93136cb604aa24cea *ubuntu-20.04-live-server-ppc64el.iso
b3e8f7d17e3a63be428b8c6592801254f6859a4ccd88b781668502fc5f5eb60a *ubuntu-20.04-live-server-s390x.iso
48167067d65c5192ffe041c9cc4958cb7fcdfd74fa15e1937a47430ed7b9de99 *ubuntu-20.04-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz
e86a9043d5394c4ae3d22d3ba62cd07d400156ec2319270d1e238ba5a0d17d9b *ubuntu-20.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi.img.xz
b45165ed3cd437b9ffad02a2aad22a4ddc69162470e2622982889ce5826f6e3d *ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
443511f6bf12402c12503733059269a2e10dec602916c0a75263e5d990f6bb93 *ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso
a2f5955378817705aad0d05a1acafec8ae14c7a08c45975a6e1444b90531824f *ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-arm64.iso
5c8cee31309148a190af585dec1800a98b8b0bc34f74bf5d13e05c6e479e29a4 *ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-ppc64el.iso
e70b6a3573378c5511102255fd30d953504993ca0410f734a94ead1877c0cc6f *ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-s390x.iso
aadc64a1d069c842e56a4289fe1a6b4b5a0af4efcf95bcce78eb2a80fe5270f4 *ubuntu-20.04.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz
bfd1eee56f7e346e1645666fc184af854c536b3ab4e1ce49d06c266f21b1ee46 *ubuntu-20.04.1-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi.img.xz
e2ce1771e352b04cfdef5bf6583f6a7d62b1f2967903fae512506d18d251a434 *ubuntu-20.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
```